# Dos create a batch file and run with multiple C++ programs

Tags: c++, batch-file, dos

Respected sirs,

My name is @nimit. I want to create a batch file and run it in a DOS prompt.  The batch file will execute a C++ program I've written. The output should be stored in a single text-file.  How can I do this?

The C++ program output should be stored in a particular text file.

Thanks in advance, 
@nimit

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
programname > outputgoeshere.txt
```

---

To collect outputs:

```
programname1 >> outputgoeshere.txt
programname2 >> outputgoeshere.txt
programname3 >> outputgoeshere.txt
```

Comment: Probably append rather than overwrite?

Comment: but i want create batch file then it output goes in a text file in a dos

suppose i have 3 c++ program that output store in a single text file

Comment: appending would use >> instead of single > (which is overwrite)

Comment: but how to create the batch file in dos

Comment: Try either `edit batchfile.bat` or `copy con batchfile.bat`. The latter will let you enter the file line by line. When you're done, press Ctrl+Z and then enter.

Comment: @user - put those statements inside a text-file with an extension of .bat, and you'll have your batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Shell scripting (Batch files are a form of that) is something that every programmer should know how to do.  I found a really great book on it a few years ago: Unix Shell Programming by Stephen Kochan and Patrick Wood.  Granted, it's Unix -- and bash is far more powerful than DOS, but the principles are the same.  Windows is picking up a lot of the tools that bash offers with powershell.

For a great website that lists out all of the CMD programs, visit http:// ss64.com/nt/ .  That site also lists comparable bash and powershell commands.  I also like how he shows you how to implement pseudo-functions, command line parameters, and all manner of cool things in batch files: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The following will redirect program output (stdout) to a file (overwrite file or create it if it does not exist)

```
$ command-name > output.log
```

The following will redirect program output (stdout) to a file (append file or create it if it does not exist)

```
$ command-name >> output.log
$ command-name >> output.log
```

The following will redirect program error message to a file called error.log:

```
$ command-name 2> error.log
```

Redirecting the standard error (stderr) and stdout to file, Use the following syntax:

```
$ command-name &> output_error.log
```